# Schedule alarm Android app

Tags: java, android

I have some trouble ring an alarm on android-studio app. First, I have a method, called with a button ( onClick), then I create alarmManager in this, and try to call a class AlarmReceiver to ring the alarm. The problem is that the program running never go in my AlarmReceiver class, and I don't understand why. Let me show you the code:

```java
public void sendMessage(View v) {

    long time = currentTimeMillis();
    Toast.makeText(this, "ALARM ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 58);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bjr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);}
```

This is the method called when click on button, and now this is the AlarmReceiver:

```java
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver
{


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null)
    {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();
}
}
```

So, when I run the app, then click on button, the word " ALARM ON" and "bjr" is printed, but the text so in AlarmReceiver "Alarm! Wake up!" Is never printed, so the app never go in this class, I need to know why.

My android manifest :

```java
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.beantunes.myapplication">


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".vue.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <receiver android:name=".vue.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name=".vue.DisplayMessageActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

`

Comment: post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I think you're missing: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

Comment: I have put this in androidManifest, still doesn't work :'(

Comment: Can you share your project? I will test it in my app

Comment: Thank you so much ofr your help, i created a github link:

https://github.com/LeBane/AndroidAlarm/tree/master/MyApplication/app/src/main/java/com/example/beantunes/myapplication

Comment: when do you want your alarm to happen?

Comment: That's good it worked, i just created an other project begin to 0. The only thing changed i think was just in the manifest: <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true">